# Animate the div left and right using css margins in jquery

Tags: html, jquery, css

on clicking on button first time div should animate to right by 300px. When clicking  2nd time on button div should animate to left 300px. same for next click.

I have tried but it only moves to left but how can I toggle to move the div to right again?

code -

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("button").click(function(){
                $("div").animate({ marginLeft: "300px"});
            });
        });
 </script>

<style>
    button{
        color:white;
        background-color: red;
        padding: 10px 20px;
    }
    div{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: yellow;
        margin: 20px 50px;
    }
</style>
```

HTML -

```
<button>Click me</button>
<div>Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve this use `toggleClass()` instead of `animate()` to add/remove the class on successive clicks. Then you can control the animation using `transition` in CSS, which performs far better than JS. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("div").toggleClass('right');
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 20px 50px;
  transition: margin-left 300ms;
}

div.right {
  margin-left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<div>Hello</div>
```

> I specifically wanted to achieve the solution using Jquery Animation. Can we get the solution using Jquery animation

In this case you need to check what the current margin is and set the new value based on that. However you should note that the CSS approach above is by far the better practice to use.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $("button").click(function() {
    let margin = $('div').css('margin-left') == '50px' ? '300px' : '50px';
    $("div").animate({'margin-left': margin});
  });
});
```

```css
button {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
  padding: 10px 20px;
}

div {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: yellow;
  margin: 20px 50px;
  transition: margin-left 300ms;
}

div.right {
  margin-left: 300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Click me</button>
<div>Hello</div>
```

Comment: I specifically wanted to achieve the solution using Jquery Animation. Can we get the solution using Jquery animation @Rory McCrossan?

Comment: Note that the [`Element.animate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/animate) function is vanilla JS, not jQuery.

Comment: @OskarGrosser well there is ***also*** a native `animate()` method, but this is obviously using the jQuery one: https://api.jquery.com/animate

Comment: My bad, I somehow thought that `$()` returns a regular `Element`-object, not a `jQuery`-object. You are absolutely right. But the `Element.animate()` and `jQuery.animate()` function in this case work exactly the same.